# How to transform Gremlin Tinkerpop Vertex to a POJO

Tags: java, tinkerpop3

Is there a simple way or an already available library where I can transform a [Vertex](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.3/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html) to a POJO. The POJO will have field names and values from the properties of the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Gremlin step to do that. The best you can do in Gremlin is to use a lambda:

```
gremlin> class Person { String name }
==>true
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> p = g.V(1).map{new Person(name:it.get().value('name'))}.next()
==>Person@2d64c100
gremlin> p.name
==>marko
```

Of course, lambdas aren't recommended as they don't work with all graph providers and have other drawbacks.

The other alternative is to use an Object Graph Mapper like [Ferma](http://syncleus.com/Ferma/), [gremlin-ogm](https://github.com/karthicks/gremlin-ogm), etc.